# $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence in E such that $\forall T\in B(E,F),T(x_n) $ converges then $x_n$ also converges

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> $E,F$ are 2 Banach Spaces such that $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence in $E$ such that $\forall T\in B(E,F)$ such that $T(x_n) $ converges then $x_n$ also converges.

I thought to apply the Uniform Boundedness principle. But I could not succeed.

**Please Can any  One just give me Some Hint SO that I could solve this problem?**

Any Help will  be appreciated

Comment: As soon as there is an injective operator $T\in B(E,F)$ with closed range, then the claim certainly holds. Otherwise I don't know.

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to prove that $(x_n)$ converges in the norm topology, this isn't true.  In the case that $F=\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ (depending on which field your Banach space $E$ is defined over), then the assumptions imply that $(x_n)$ is weakly convergent. But for **most** infinite-dimensional Banach space $E$, there exist sequences which are weakly convergent but not norm convergent (the only Banach space that I know of where weak convergence of a sequence implies norm convergence is $\ell_1$).

Comment: Correct. But what if $F$ is infinite-dimensional?

Comment: I'll have to think about that, but I imagine there are cases where the result fails to hold.

Comment: I guess so, too. Depends on the geometry of $F$.

Comment: Dear Sir Can you please provide me some counterexample

Comment: @SRJ $E=\ell_2(\mathbb N)$, $F=\mathbb C$, and the sequence $(x_n)$ is defined by $x_n(k)=1$ if $k=n$ and $=0$ otherwise.  Then $(x_n)$ converges weakly to $0$, but is not norm convergent.